Help With Partially-Censored Phrase: "トリマ皆デマ〇クデモ行カネ？"
I've been working on subtitling this series on Scratch, when in episode 3, I came across one particularly annoying phrase with a maru in it. To make it harder, the phrase was in katakana instead of hiragana, and they didn't seem to change any loan words to hiragana for this character. That being said, I tried to figure out what it could possibly mean in context and have had no luck.
Attempting to convert properly to hiragana, I got a possible solution:
とりまみんなでマ〇クでも行かね？
But I am not sure if this is correct, because maybe more of it is supposed to be in katakana (e.g. デモ instead of でも). I'm honestly really confused at this point, and if anyone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
Phrase (written as-is w/out hiragana): トリマ皆デマ〇クデモ行カネ？
Project link: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/1066535323

マックでしょう。マクドナルド。


とりまみんなでマ〇クでも行かね？

To break it down:
とりま -- slangy abbreviation of とりあえず、まあ
みんなで -- we all together
マ〇ク -- マック、マクドナルド McDonald's
でも -- 助詞「でも」 → See here, here
行かね？ -- 行かない？行きませんか？（勧誘）
Putting it back together:

とりあえず、まあ、みんなでマクドナルド（に）でも行かない？

